# Sort products leaving out of stock at the end

Tags: woocommerce

There are many answers in StackOverflow, but old ones, none has worked with the lastest version of Woocommerce for me.

My page is already sorting by recent products, but I like to move all sold out products to the last pages.

Last codes I've tried:

1:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q ) {
if (   $q->is_main_query()        // Only target the main query
     && $q->is_post_type_archive() // Change to suite your needs
) {
    $q->set( 'meta_key', '_stock_status' );
    $q->set( 'orderby',  'meta_value'    );
    $q->set( 'order',    'ASC'           );
}
}, PHP_INT_MAX );
```

2:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', function( $query_args, $atts, $loop_name ){
    if( $loop_name == 'recent_products' ){
        $query_args['meta_query'] = array( array(
            'key'     => '_stock_status',
            'value'   => 'outofstock',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
        ) );
    }
    return $query_args;
}, 10, 3);
```

Comment: Since woocommerce 3, the product stock status is not anymore handled as meta data… See [**here this related thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46503228/3730754) that will put you on the right track.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, thanks for your help, would you be able to help on how I would implement this on an answer? Thank you very much for your time

Comment: I have been trying, But I didn't find out yet the way to make it working as you would like. If I have something functional I will make an answer, of course.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't see anything on the web talking about this, I guess this change screwed up the sorting thing. Thank you anyways!