# WP_Query issue when trying to get out of stock products in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, shortcode

I'm using shortcode to display all sold out `WooCommerce` items on a `WordPress` page. It works fine, except for throwing an error:

```
Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress_4\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\class-wc-query.php on line 688
```

I figure that this means `array_filter()` expects an array, but is given `null` from the following code in my `functions.php`:

```
add_shortcode( 'out_of_stock_products', 'show_out_of_stock_products_shortcode' );
  
function show_out_of_stock_products_shortcode() {

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_stock_status',
                'value' => 'outofstock',
            )
        ),
        'fields' => 'ids',
    );
    
    $product_ids = get_posts( $args ); 
    $product_ids = implode( ",", $product_ids );
    
    return do_shortcode("[products ids='$product_ids']");
}
```

Shortcode: `[out_of_stock_products]`

Here's the `WooCommerce` function that expects the array but is given `null`:

```
public function get_meta_query( $meta_query = array(), $main_query = false ) {
    if ( ! is_array( $meta_query ) ) {
        $meta_query = array();
    }
    return array_filter( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', $meta_query, $this ) ); //line 688
}
```

I'm not sure how to fix this. Maybe there is a better way to display sold out products altogether, though I like this version.

Could anyone help me fix this?

Source: https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-display-stock-products-shortcode/

**Edit:**

As @LoicTheAztec suggests, another bit of code than the ones posted above is responsible:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'show_only_instock_products', 10, 2 );

show_only_instock_products( $meta_query, $query ) {
    if (  is_woocommerce() ) {
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'     => '_stock_status',
            'value'   => 'outofstock',
            'compare' => '!='
        );
        return $meta_query;
    }
}
```

I am using this to hide sold products from `WooCommerce`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2**

To get out of stock products, you can also use instead:

1. A `WC_Query` using `wc_get_products()` function as follows:

```php
add_shortcode( 'out_of_stock_products', 'show_out_of_stock_products_shortcode' );
function show_out_of_stock_products_shortcode() {

    $product_ids = (array) wc_get_products( array(
        'status'       => 'publish',
        'limit'        => -1,
        'stock_status' => 'outofstock',
        'return'       => 'ids',
    ) );

    $product_ids = empty($product_ids) ? '' : implode( ',', $product_ids );

    return empty($product_ids) ? '' : do_shortcode("[products ids='$product_ids']");
}
```

2). A `WP_Query` with a tax query like:

```php
add_shortcode( 'out_of_stock_products', 'show_out_of_stock_products_shortcode' );
function show_out_of_stock_products_shortcode() {

    $product_ids = (array) get_posts( array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'fields'         => 'ids',
        'tax_query' => array( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => array('outofstock'),
        ) ),
    ) );

    $product_ids = empty($product_ids) ? '' : implode( ',', $product_ids );

    return empty($product_ids) ? '' : do_shortcode("[products ids='$product_ids']");
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Related: [Hide "out of stock" products with custom meta data In Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46501271/hide-out-of-stock-products-with-custom-meta-data-in-woocommerce/46503228#46503228)

---

**Addition:** The problem comes from your edit (last code).

Also since WooCommerce 3, you should use instead the following:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_tax_query', 'show_only_instock_products', 10, 2 );
show_only_instock_products( $tax_query, $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => array('outofstock'),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        );
    }
    return $tax_query;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you! I tried both. Unfortunately the same error remains...

Comment: @Cinder I tried your code and mine, and I don't have any error (last WooCommerce version on storefront theme), so there is something else that is making trouble, It can be some other code, a plugin or even your theme.

Comment: @Cinder **Updated again** … I have lightly updated my code… Can you try it again, to see if this solve the issue?

Comment: Thanks again! It's still not working, I tried both your updated versions. I have another bit of code that hides sold out products from WooCommerce. I will add it to my initial post for reference, since if I remove this code, yours and mine work. So it has to be that.

Comment: I'm getting an 'unexpected if' error from your last code. If I add 'function' before `show_only_instock_products`, the error is gone. But then it doesn't hide outofstock items from the store. So I'm probably still doing something wrong. I'll work on figuring it out. Thank you for you help!

Comment: When using `( is_woocommerce() )` in my if-statement and `'operator' => 'NOT IN'` as an additional argument for the `array`, it seems to be working! Again, thanks a lot! I got a real headache over this!

Comment: @Cinder Oups! yes I forgot that it was for products in stock only… Updated. Now is_woocommerce() is not required as the hook `woocommerce_product_query_tax_query` is used by woocommerce only.